# How to force Firefox to open devtools on each tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is there any way how to enable opening of devtools on all new tabs? I'd like to have devtools opened to be able to comfortably debug popup windows.

Comment: I also miss this feature. An application is opening the browser with some link that instantly redirects to some error page.

Comment: Bug/feature request tracked in Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1569859

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but Firefox Seems to recently have added this option. You can have a read [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html). Basically you can use the dev tools of the parent window to analyze popups using the Browser Toolbox ( Open using `ctrl + alt + shift + i` )
and selecting the **Disable Popup autohide option**. With this setting enabled, popups will stay open and you can analyze their contents by selecting them using the node picker tool. This isn't the best approach but it seems like the only way to achieve what you seemingly want to have. I cant really say much about monitoring network traffic of popups as I haven't needed to do that yet but as far as just analyzing the contents of a popup, this seems like a valid option.

Comment: It looks like the referenced article https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html deals with debugging of browser itself and debugging browser addons. The question is about devtools of a page.

Comment: yes and no. While yes it can be used to debug the browser, the official issue on mozilla forms ultimately links here. besides the question was about debugging popup windows and as of right now, there isnt a better way. If you read the article "Debugging popups¶

It’s hard to debug popups, because the browser hides them as soon as you click outside them. There is a way to disable this behavior. Click the toolbox menu and select Disable popup auto-hide." and then the question "
I'd like to have devtools opened to be able to comfortably debug popup windows.
" makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry Kulikov has developed a plugin for Firefox that does exactly this. You can find it here: https://github.com/dmitry-kulikov/firefox-devtools-auto-open
and can be installed from the firefox add-on store here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/devtools-auto-open

From my experience it does not bind to the new tab from the start. As such you might miss some network entries. I expect this is due to this being an add-on and not natively implemented.

Comment: Looks like this addon no longer exists.