# trigger opening of devtools automatically for some links

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I need help launching devtools automatically when opening certain links. For example if I hold ALT key and click on a link, the link should open with devtools logging all netwrok requests made.

until now after opening a link I press F12 to open devtools but some requests made will not be seen because of the delay in pressing F12 key.

I expect to trigger opening of devtools to open and log all requests in network tab and other errors, logs and warning in console tab.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640575/how-to-force-firefox-to-open-devtools-on-each-tab) old post answer your question?

Comment: @AndrewAllen no, the addon is not avaiable anymore and it would be nice to be able to open it only for some links (by using a trigger/key on keyboard) not for every link I open.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54501918/3367974), it may helps.